# Convert a yyyymm-integer to date

Tags: r, date, integer

I would like to convert a `YYYYMM-integer` to a Date without converting it to character (=is there a mdy-function like in SAS?). I would like to replace this code:

```
 dateint<-201511
 datestr<-paste(toString(dateint,length=8),'01')
 date<-as.Date(datestr,'%Y%m%d')
 print(date)
 class(date)
```

with a working version of this. If possible the resulting class should be a date too:

```
 year<-dateint %% 100
 month<-floor(dateint/100)
 date2<-ISOdate(year,month,1) # I can't make this work ..
 print(date2)
 class(date2)
```

Thanks & kind regards

Comment: Please explain why your solution is not sufficient for your purposes. Due to leap years (and the complex rules regarding them) a solution that doesn't parse a character string (thereby using OS facilities) is not feasible.

Comment: Why converting to character is not ok?

Comment: In my mind converting a number to a character and then back to a number (=date) just feels strange. Maybe this is a stupid question - or let me put the question this way: Would somebody with R experience consider the first piece of code proper programming?

Comment: But what you have there is not really a number.

Comment: @r.user.05apr your code is fine. Only you do not need to use toString, as.character would suffice. You do not even need to use that, `paste` will automatically convert numeric values to string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package **lubridate** has a function `ymd`, which accepts numeric input:

```
> library(lubridate)
> ymd(20151101)
[1] "2015-11-01 UTC"
```

You need however to add the day at the end.

Comment: It converts to character internally.

Comment: I did not state that it did not :)